# Question on Rudin Exercise 3.1

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Exercise 3.1 in Baby Rudin states:

> Prove that convergence $\{s_n\}$ implies convergence of $\{|s_n|\}$. Is the converse true?

My question is not on how to do this, but on interpreting what Rudin was asking.

First, the chapter deals with sequences of complex numbers, so it seems safe to safe that $s_n \in \mathbb{C}$. Of course, the sequence of modulu will lie in $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$. For complex numbers, we do have an earlier fact from chapter $1$ that states that
$$
||x|-|y|| \leq |x-y|.
$$
However, the more general definition of sequence converge doesn't use absolute value to denote distance, but the more general $d(x,q)$. That is, it states that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N$ so that $n \geq N$ implies $d(s_n, s) < \epsilon$.

The proofs of these fact seem to rely on using this absolute-value/Euclidean metric.

Am I missing something? Is this the only available metric on $\mathbb{C}$? Or is there a more general proof that does not rely on the fact I mentioned?

Comment: If you think about it for 5 seconds you will find an example where $|s_n|$ converges and $s_n$ doesn't, no matter what distance is used.

Comment: It's not the only metric but it's the only metric that Rudin concerned with. If we view the Reals as an ordered field with the least upper bound property then absolute-value/Euclidean metric it is the one metric that comes directly from and integrated with this definition of the reals or of the concept of the complex as an extension of the reals.

Comment: With this in mind, though, why would Rudin write the more general distance formula in the definition of convergence? Is this only to illustrate that we could in theory extend convergence to a general metric space?

Comment: @Matt. P that is correct.